# How to remove .js suffix from Angular imports

Tags: angular, systemjs

I want to remove .js suffix from Angular imports.

**Not wanted (now workable):** `import { Example } from './whatever/example.js';`

**Wanted:** `import { Example } from './whatever/example';`

I suspect I am missing a configuration in the `systemjs.config.js`.

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      // other libraries

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: have you tried using `defaultJSExtensions: true` in your `System.config(...`?

Comment: @Wernerson Yes, it is not working. zone.js:2224 GET http://localhost:8000/app/whatever/example 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this in packages:

```
'.': {
    defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
}
```

Such that packages now looks like:

```
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
'.': {
    defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
},
app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
},
rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```